# How come my reputation points have decreased without a reason?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation points have been cut down without any reason, neither a notification nor an activity log for the same is available. I had 101 reputation points, but it got sliced to 88 without any activity, nor is there any downvote or something.

Comment: go to help center

Comment: I have the same question.. I went to the reputation tab also as per the answer given but could not find anything.

Comment: You can't delete the post because it has an answer with a positive score. Also changing the entire question is not the correct way to ask that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[One of your questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335035/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-okhttp-in-nougat-devices) got deleted.

You can see this by going to the [Reputation tab on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7777699/saurabh?tab=reputation) and checking the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom.